# Using TMS WEB Core and JSON

Tags: json, delphi, web, tms, tms-web-core

Starting from a VCL project to TMS WEB Core, I can no longer use "System.JSON".

Having declared :

```
LJsonValue: TJsonValue;
LJsonArray: TJsonArray;
LJSonString: TJsonString;
```

How to translate VCL line

```
LJsonValue := LJsonValue.GetValue<TJSonValue>('choices');
LJSonString := LJSonArray.Items[0].GetValue<TJSONString>('text');
```

for TMS WEB Core? I can't find the solution not being comfortable with JSON.

Comment: TMS Webcore has a  `WEBLib.JSON` unit.  Have you included this unit?

Comment: Yes, but how to modify these two lines with GetValue?

Comment: Are you parsing a WebHTTPRequest response?  If so, I can post and example..

Comment: var
  LCb: TTMSFNCCloudBase;
  LPostdata: string;
  LJsonValue: TJsonValue;
  LJsonArray: TJsonArray;
  LJSonString: TJsonString;

if Lcb.RequestResult.Success then
    begin
      LJsonValue := TJSonObject.ParseJSONValue(Lcb.RequestResult.ResultString);
      LJsonValue := LJsonValue.GetValue<TJSonValue>('choices');

      if LJsonValue is TJSonArray then
      begin
        LJSonArray := LJsonValue as TJSonArray;
        LJSonString := LJSonArray.Items[0].GetValue<TJSONString>('text');
        Result := LJSonString.Value;
      end;
    end;

Comment: Is the response an array?

Answer (score 1):

Basically in TMS Web Core you can use the `WEBLib.JSON`-Unit. With that you can translate your VCL-Code to this:

```
uses WEBLib.JSON;

...  
var
  LJsonValue: TJSObject;
  LJsonValue2: TJSObject;
  LJsonArray: TJSArray;
  LString: String;
begin
  ...
  LJsonValue2 := TJSJSON.parseObject(LJsonValue.Properties['choices']);
  LString := String(TJSJSON.parseObject(LJsonArray[0]).Properties['text']);
```

With the function `TJSJSON.parseObject` from the unit `JS` you can parse a `JSValue` to a `TJSObject` and with that you can access all the Properties of the underlying JSON-Node.

You can also cast `TJSObject` to a `TJSArray` and iterate over it´s items.